# How select data dividual character uppercase and lowercase in DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a DataTable dt , it has values:

```
Col1 Col2
M     12332223
m     23223333
```

I code:

`Dim  dr() as DataRow =dt.Select("Col1='M'")`

Result: return dr has 2 rows: m and M.

Why? I want to get 1 row has value = M. How fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Just want to highlight that this is not the LINQ Select, but a DataTable own function. That is, `dt.AsEnumerable().Select` and `dt.Select` are completely different stories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Datatable searches are case insensitive by default. Set the CaseSensitive property on the datatable to True

```
dt.CaseSensitive = True
```